# Install a file only if both the features are selected

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, wix3.6, wix3.7

There are two features - feature1 and feature2;I need to install a file only if both the features are selected, for which i have written:

```
  <Component Id="cmpCFA15F2C5DC1EEEA145360EA017FB322" Guid="*">
    <Condition><![CDATA[(&feature1=3) AND (&feature2=3)]]></Condition>
    <File Id="filCB4BD4847E5BDFC79A4308D520941A22" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Binsourcedir)\hello.exe" />
  </Component>
```

But it does not work, any help is appreciated.What is that i am missing?.Thanks in advance

Comment: In case this applies and you've overlooked it, if feature2 is a sub-feature of feature1 then you just need to reference the component in feature2.

Comment: If you put that file in its own separate hidden feature, I think it might work if you publish an AddLocal event to add that feature, conditioned on those two other features being selected.

Answer (score 2):

Feature states in component conditions won't work. See http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/09/feature-states-in-component-conditions/ for my breakdown of why it doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps always isntall the file to a dummy directory and then emit a temp record into MSI to clone the file to the real directory if one of the two required features is, will be or will continue to be installed?   Thanks for reminding me of this.  Eitherway seems like too complicated of a story for the installer.  I'd refactor the app to make life simpler.